# How can I remove html text in React native

Tags: html, react-native

Hi I am recieving html text in my JSON. how can i remove it in React native?
{

"title": "Dealing with  &#038

Depression &
}

Comment: Please add some more detail.

Comment: I am calling an api in which in i am recievinf some of the text in html format like <p> &#038 </p> like that. Now I want to remove this text in display only my formal text.

Comment: Are you aware of what are the tags you will get from API?

Comment: no, i am getting only in my title object

Comment: Whenever you are using this title user like --->
 a.replace("&#038",'') or there are many then use regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to remove HTML tags.

```js
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
const result = JSON.title.replace(regex, '');
```

Comment: I have tried this but no luck.. i am using it like

 const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
and in my return statement 
 <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.title}>
                      {item.title.replace(regex, ' ')}
                    </Text>

Comment: <\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a> Try this regex

Comment: no man it is still showing..now i am setting the state like 

  const [regex, setRegex] = useState('\sa[^>]*>(.?)<\s*/\s*a');

and calling like 

 <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.title}>
                      {item.title.replace(setRegex, '')}
                    </Text>

is that true?

Comment: is that includes numbers too?